# Use of Open/SaveFileDialog boxes and Custom Dialogs

Tags: caliburn.micro

I'm a long time WinForms coder and I'm just starting to get into the swing of things with WPF, MVVM and Caliburn.micro.  I like it a lot so far...

One area has me stumped - namely Open/SaveFileDialogs.  I am trying to stay true to the MVVM pattern and keep all my dialogs as part of the View.  I have not yet found any samples that cover the usage of these built-in dialogs.

What is the standard convention to use these dialogs?
Does anyone have a sample they could share here?

Where possible, I am looking for a convention that would also apply to several custom dialogs I will be creating (i.e. one approach for all my dialogs). I believe the WindowManager of Caliburn may be the key, but I don't see any examples with Open/Save dialogs, and unfortunately I can't get the sample projects to load up in Visual Studio.

Thanks in advance!

BW

Comment: The WindowManager is the key and suggestion would be to extend the existing to include the option for a Open/Save Dialog.  Here is an IDE (probably could be used more than just an IDE) that uses Caliburn.Micro, recently found it haven't had a chance to play but wow...https://github.com/tgjones/gemini/tree/master/src/Gemini/Framework/Results

Comment: Thanks.  I will proceed with my current implementation as a learning experiment, but this resources looks great as a learning tool.